# How to export all the ContentDocumentLink records in Salesforce?

Tags: contentdocumentlink

I am doing analysis to get the number of files attached to the each object inside Salesforce.
I found that there is a standard object named ContentDocumentLink which has the reference of the each file(i.e. LinkedEntityId field maps the file with the corresponding object).
I have tried the approaches listed below but I didn't get the expected result :

- I have tried to export all the ContentDocumentLink records using Dataloader. But there is a query limitation on the ContentDocumentLink object,it looks like we must provide the LinkedEntityId or ContentDocumentId in filter to export a data. Since I want to get the count of files by grouping the objects from ContentDocumentLink, I cannot specify any objects in my filter as In would require data of every object that has a file attached to their record.
- I have tried to export using Data Export option in Setup. I have scheduled this export 8 days ago. But so far it shows that 'Your export has been queued'. I don't know how this got stuck or not and when it will be completed.

Apart from the above methods, do anyone have a solution to calculate the No of files present in each object based records.
(Eg: Account - 3000 Files Attached
Contact - 2000 files Attached
Opportunity - 1500 files Attached, Etc)

Comment: Did you find any solution for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

So there are many approaches to this problem. But I will mention two. One with code and the other is a manual process.

Code

1. Supposing you have all the objects you want to search as a text in a custom setting, we can write a batch job and by using the Schema describe, get each object in a batch one by one and count the documents attached ([Content Documents](http://theblogreaders.com/insert-files-using-salesforce-apex/)). You can aggregate the count in your finish method and send an email once done.

Manual
2. Schedule a report on each object you want to count, and then aggregate the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Official™ answer from Salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313973&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1

tl;dr: Make each contentdocument visible to to the exporting user.